# Не могу сделать табы с картинками

Tags: jquery, html5

```js
function ImageTabs() {
  var WrapGalary = $(".galary_wrap");
  var MenuGalary = WrapGalary.find(".galary_menu>li");
  var ContentGalary = WrapGalary.find(".img_content_all");
  ContentGalary.not(":first").hide();
  MenuGalary.each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr("data-type", "tab" + i);
  });
  ContentGalary.each(function(i) {
    $(this).attr("data-type", "tab" + i);
  });
  MenuGalary.click(function() {
    var getWrapGalary = $(this).closest(".galary_wrap");
    var dataTab = $(this).attr("data-type");
    getWrapGalary.find(".galary_menu>li").removeClass("active");
    $(this).find("li").addClass("active");

    getWrapGalary.find(ContentGalary).hide();
    getWrapGalary.find(ContentGalary).filter("[data-type=" + dataTab + "]").show();

  });
}
ImageTabs();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="galary_wrap">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
      <div class="slider_menu">
        <ul class="galary_menu">
          <li>All /</li>
          <li>entertaiment /</li>
          <li>sport /</li>
          <li>bussnnes /</li>
          <li>bulding</li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="galary_content">
    <div class="row">
      <!--  <div class="block_1">-->
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="img_content_all">
          <img src="../Shablon_16/image/slide_1.png" width="458px" height="200px" alt="Slide" class="sport">
          <div class="mask_1">
            <div class="plus"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="img_content_all">
          <img src="../Shablon_16/image/slide_2.png" alt="Slide" width="222px" height="200px" class="all">
          <div class="mask_2">
            <div class="plus"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="img_content_all">
          <img src="../Shablon_16/image/slide_3.png" alt="Slide" width="235px" height="200px" class="all buss">
          <div class="mask_3">
            <div class="plus"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- </div>-->
    </div>

    <div class="row">
      <!-- <div class="block_2">-->
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <div class="img_content_all">
          <img src="../Shablon_16/image/slide_4.png" width="217px" height="200px" alt="Slide" class="bulding">
          <div class="mask_4">
            <div class="plus"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3">

        <div class="img_content_all">
          <img src="../Shablon_16/image/slide_5.png" alt="Slide" width="230px" height="200px" class="enterteiment">
          <div class="mask_5">
            <div class="plus"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6">
        <div class="img_content_all">
          <img src="../Shablon_16/image/slide_6.png" alt="Slide" width="469px" height="200px" class="busnis">
          <div class="mask_6">
            <div class="plus"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- </div>-->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Проблема в том, что когда нажимаю на список - оно показывает одну картинку, а нужно, чтобы показывало группу картинок!

Как это сделать?

Comment: Даст кто ответ?

Comment: http://jqueryui.com/tabs/